# How can I use iOS certificates in the non-default (login) keychain?

Tags: ios, xcode4, keychain

I have a bash script that builds and signs my iOS apps for adhoc over-the-air distribution to testers.

The signing process requires that the keychain be unlocked, which means storing the password in plain-text in my script.  I'd rather this not be the main keychain (login) and create a separate keychain just for these keys/certificates where the password isn't that big of a deal.

I can create the new keychain and put all the keys/certs in there, but xcode 4 seems to only look in the login keychain.  Is there a way to change this, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate keychain, and xcode 4 (at least, I just tested and confirmed with xcode 4.5 on mountain lion) will look not only in the login keychain, but all keychains, including the new keychain.

So it is good, and you can store just the keys/certs that you need in the new keychain.